Run Docker Test Container in gitlab with Maven
I'm attempting to run a CI/CD pipeline using GitLab CI with Kubernetes runners. I'm using a docker:dind base image to build and deploy my Java application with Maven. Here is the Dockerfile I am using:
FROM docker:dind

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache openjdk21 maven git

ENV MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/java/maven-3.9.8
ENV PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH

CMD ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]

However, when I run the pipeline, I encounter the following log error:
Could not find a valid Docker environment.

I am using Kubernetes runners to execute my CI/CD jobs, and it seems like my configuration is unable to find or start a Docker environment correctly.
I tried using different dind versions, but i think the problem is related to the Kubernetes runners, because the docker wont be in one single machine (as it was before)

I think. It is because Docker is not more a part of kubernetes installation. Just google about it. For example. https://kodekloud.com/blog/kubernetes-removed-docker-what-happens-now/
Most likely you have another CRI containerD. Just take another base image. some alphine or ubuntu.
